# what's wrong with my cron command?

Tags: mac, cron

In my cron file (Mac, El Capitan) I have a line that simply updates a file name with a date every day.

```
0 1 * * * mv /Users/me/0backup* /Users/me/0backup_$(date +"\%m-\%d-\%y")
```

This allows me to quickly check that backups have been done. This seems to work fine on other machines, but on this particular machine it works (the file name DOES get updated), but every day when it is executed I get mailed errors:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What's going on? Why am I getting these errors?

Comment: Did you copy/paste this directly from `crontab -l`? Do things change if you use `$(date +'%m-%d-%y')`

Comment: Yes, I used crontab -e to edit. I will try using single quotes. Interesting idea. But on more modern operating systems, I'm not getting this error.

Comment: “More modern?”  macOS is a current *certified* Unix.  You don’t get more modern than that.

Comment: Even with `"`, the `\ ` are not required. I still suspect a hidden/non-visible special character somewhere. Also, are you sure `/Users/me/0backup*` expands to one file only?

Comment: True, Mountain Lion is UNIX 03-compliant and certified, but Lion was not. Yes, I'm sure that wildcard only expands to one file.

Comment: @nohillside `%` characters in a crontab command must be escaped, or cron will convert them into line breaks. See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running/39515330#39515330).

Comment: OK, problem solved. I have a bunch of stuff in my cron account, and I didn't notice that this particular directive was duplicated. The clue was "line 0" and "line 1". I didn't realize this erroneous command was up at the top and THAT one had a formatting error. The reason the command was working was because the duplicate was formatted properly! Apologies for my stupidity.

Comment: It usually helps to include the whole crontab in a question and not just one line. Also, could you please post the solution as an answer and explain what actually was wrong?

Comment: I learned something here! I've used `cron` for a long time, but never realized that a `%` had to be *escaped*! But just for post-mortem purposes, I would really appreciate if you'd post your answer here with the **before** and **after**.

Answer (score 0):

This was a mistake on my part. I had TWO sorta identical lines in my cron file that did the date updating. I probably added them at different times. ONE line had a formatting error. The other did not. So I was getting an error from that one line, and the other line did the job properly. Pay attention to to the line numbers in the errors that it gives. Thank you to the responders who tried to help me out.

Comment: This is a great troubleshooting step. Remove everything from crontab and test one only , then restore the others.